# Permanent change to 1 div out of many of the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, event-listener

I have stumbled on to a problem which I cannot find the solution to, for some time now, and it is kind of a drag, but hey, I will try to be as precice as possible, there is no stupid question so here goes.

This is a `DIV` table for appointments and a page, these green circles are divs also and there are 209 divs total, `divs` are clickable and once clicked they open up a new page in a new tab which asks the user to to enter his info Name, Last Name etc. and make an appointment.

[image]
 When the user enters what is asked of him he clicks a button makes an appointment and the `div` that has been clicked in the previous "table" page permanently changes color to **red**, so when someone else visits the "table" page sees that the time for the appointment is unavailable.
I have come up with this.

**TABLE PAGE CODE:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var myLoadedColor = localStorage.getItem('myDataStorage');
        document.getElementById('L1').style.backgroundColor = myLoadedColor;
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName("circleBase type1");
    for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        d[i].onclick = function() {
            window.open("EnterInformation.html");               
        }
    }
}
    window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {
        if (event.storageArea === localStorage) {
            var myLoadedColor = localStorage.getItem('myDataStorage');
            document.getElementById('L1').style.backgroundColor = myLoadedColor;

        }
    }, false);
```

**APPOINTMENT PAGE CODE:**

```
 function SaveInfo() {

        localStorage.Yritys = $('#Yritys').val();
        localStorage.Henkilönimi = $('#Henkilönimi').val();
        localStorage.Asema_yrityksessa = $('#Asema_yrityksessa').val();
        localStorage.Puhelin_Nr = $("#Puhelin_Nr").val();
        localStorage.e_Mail = $('#e_Mail').val();
        localStorage.Keskustelun_aihe = $('#Keskustelun_aihe').val();
        alert("You have successfully made an appointment");                        
    }

    function closeSelf() {
        window.close(this);

    }

    function changeColor() {

        myCustomColor = 'red';
        localStorage.setItem('myDataStorage', myCustomColor);

    }
```

With this code It works but only for 1 div the first one.
My question is do I have to add `Id` to all of the 209 `divs` I have and then copy this code 209 times for each and every one of the `divs` and create a specific storage for each of them? or is there an easier way to do this?
Ajax is like an acquaintance to me.

Any advice would be helpful if it helps me achieve this goal, because I can't sleep and keep thinking about the ways to end the agony!

Comment: apart from your current issue, i see that you are using `localStorage`. So if you go with that then your code will work for single pc/laptop/machine and more over with single browser of it. If any other user user their own machine then its like nobody has done any appointment so far.  `localStorage` is machine level as well as browser level storage space.

Comment: You can substitute `.className` for `id`, pass the index of the clicked `div` to opened `window`. What are elements at opened `window` referencing?

Comment: @vijayP Oh I see, one more problem not to let me sleep, what would You suggest be done? Is there an answer?

Comment: What are `$('#Yritys').val();` referencing at opened `window`?

Comment: 'L1' is the ID of the clicked div, now I know which div it is i set the id so i could test the code. `$('#Yritys').val();` is finnish for name, it just saves the appointment to localStorage.
@guest271314

Comment: You can create an object having properties matching indexes of 209 `div` elements. Set `localStorage` to the value of the property at object which matches clicked `div` index.

Comment: like an array or a list? I'm not following? Can You explain it a little bit more, I seriously haven't slept, and I have trouble focusing, sorry if I sound stupid :S
@guest271314

Comment: Basically you have to use server side storage mechanism like Database to store which time slot of any company got reserved on any particular date. So while rendering the circle/table page; from server side you will have to pass information like which all slots got reserved and depending upon them you will mark them as red. For all circle give class as `circleBase` along with unique class as `time_9`, `time_9_5`(equal to 9:30), `time_10` and so on. By this way it will be easy to target circle divs according to data that you got from server.

Comment: @vijayP Would I have to use SQL for server side storage, or is there a servers database which I can use? and what would I have to change in the code? Use Ajax? or something else? I understood it but how will the server know if it is the first company the fifth or the 12th? do I add a Unique class for that too?

Comment: Then you should get some rest. `var divs = $("div"); var arr = [{name:"abc", value:123}, {name:"def", value: 456}];` At `click` event `divs.click(function() {`var i = $(this).index(divs); localStorage.setItem(arr[i].name, arr[i].value)})` or pass `i` and object to opened `window` where the script should have access to `arr`. How do you say "what's your" followed by `Yritys`?

Comment: Yes. Correct. You will have to used SQL and any database of your choice to store the data permanently which can be accessed by your website and be served to all the users across the globe. After HTML page load you will have to execute Ajax to get all reservation status and Yes for each row you will have to give unique class like company id or number to distinguish between the rows. Its very difficult to explain all the stuff here but I hope you will get an idea out of it.